# Installation of ArcticDB library is not working on Ubuntu (EC2)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip, arcticdb

I'm trying to install this library on an EC2 instance that runs Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm getting this error:

```
$ pip install arcticdb
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement arcticdb (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for arcticdb
```

I've seen this is expected to happen on MacOS but it should work on Ubuntu.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? That library requires Python 3. You may want to try `pip3`.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.10.12. I've just tried with `pip3` and I got the same issue :(

Comment: I'm guessing, since you didn't say, that you're running this on a Graviton instance.  ArcticDB doesn't publish Linux ARM packages.

Comment: @AnonCoward I didn't know about that. Indeed I'm running a Graviton instance.

Answer (score 2):

In general there could be a few different reasons for this error.

In particular on EC2 there are two major processor architectures AMD/Intel and AWS Graviton (ARM).  ArcticDB (at least version 4.3.1 and below) has pip builds for AMD/Intel architectures but not AWS Graviton.